# In c#, how to scan very large files with a regex - or is it possible to feed a regex one char at a time?

Tags: c#, regex, large-files

I am building a tool to scan for a regex pattern in many files of arbitrarily large sizes.

I am going to do this in parallel on multiple files concurrently and therefore I want to avoid loading the entire files into memory as they can be arbitrarily large. Therefore I will chunk each file by using memory mapped files and view accessors and then scan each chunk.

My questions are:

1. How to ensure that no matches are missed if the matching text is overlapping two chunks?
2. If the Regex could be fed a char at a time and then fire events when a match is found then that could help. I would probably still have to have a max on allowed match sizes, but is it possible to do that with Regex?

Comment: It might help to add what've you tried so far, eg. your research. Q is good tho

Comment: Please also include the regex pattern(s) you're planning to use. That can be very relevant.

Comment: Are these fixed regexes or user supplied? Because regexes need to be able to backtrack arbitrarily, you pretty well have to make sure that your buffers are big enough to contain an entire match (so arbitary regexes are problematic because you won't know how big their largest possible match might be)

Comment: User supplied. It is a grep-like tool for scanning a bunch of log files. I think some simpler wildcard searching must be made, and regexes should probably be limited to line oriented scanning. But if there is some  low-level Regex like library that could work on an enumeration of bytes and make callbacks on matches (just providing start and end byte counts), that could be useful.

Comment: @Terry hits the point here. Log files are usually line-oriented (and that's no coincidence -- the reason is your use case!), and regexes will try to filter lines (and extract information from single lines). Exploit that.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean under *chunk*? What if the string to match is in two different chunks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't allow spanning lines, your buffer only needs to be one line long.

If you do allow spanning lines, then your buffers need to be as large as the largest look-back you allow + the longest line you allow.

In direct response to your question, you can't do "one character at a time" because the entire search and target strings need to exist for the comparison to work.